# Section title with lines on either side - left justified

Tags: formatting, sectioning

I am trying to create a section title that is left justified, but with lines filling out either side of the title, like this:

```
-- Section Title --------------------------
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243651/center-text-between-horizontal-lines-extending-to-the-margin-on-either-side) question and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537150/centred-section-title-with-lines-on-either-side) question cover implementing this for a centered title, but I can't figure out how to adapt the code to left justify the title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you have tried so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...